# How to prevent VS2022 from swallowing Trace output when debugger is attached?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, system.diagnostics, debugview

I'm running a .NET 7.0 project from VS2022 and I'd like to simply output all Trace messages to DebugView++. Everything works great, but *only* when there is no debugger attached. If I start debugging the project in VS, Trace.Write() goes only to the Output window. If I detach the debugger, DebugView++ will immediately begin showing the Trace messages. If I reattach the debugger, it will immediately stop writing to DebugTrace and writes in the Output window. I can switch it all day long, so it seems the Output window is redirecting all Trace output to the Output window; all I want is for VS to stop screwing with the Trace output always and forever. Is this even possible?

```
    public static class Logger
    {
        readonly static TraceListener? listener = null;

        static Logging()
        {
            Trace.Listeners.Clear();

            listener = new DefaultTraceListener();
            Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);

            Trace.AutoFlush = true;
        }

        public static void Trace(string message, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
        {
            var msg = $"[TestProject|{callerName}] {message}";

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly how things should work, not a JetBrains Rider or Visual Studio bug. DebugView does what Visual Studio and any other IDE does - it attaches to the program as an actual debugger and displays the debug output. If you attach a different debugger, whether another IDE or another tool, DebugView will no longer receive those messages

Comment: I'm sure it is, but that's exactly what I *don't* want to happen. The Output window is useless for me compared to DebugView++ since I'm dealing with a large amount of realtime tracing info and to effectively consume it all during debugging without having something like DebugView++, it would require building a whole project unto itself. I know it's possible, since there is an extension (OutputForwarder2022) to get around this but in the extension code, but it's not much help since it always crashes on load on all the machines I've tried it on.

Comment: If you're sure, you understand that what you ask is self-contradictory. If you attach the debuger, you consume the debug output. The last comment strongly suggests you're using DebugView for the wrong job. Debug output is neither a logging nor a tracing tool.  `I'm dealing with a large amount of realtime tracing info` that's what OpenTelemetry, Jaeger and ActivitySource are for. .NET libraries *already* have a ton of diagnostic events and listeners and NONE of them involves Debug output.

Comment: In fact, there are tracing and metrics instrumentation libraries already for the .NET platform itself (including the runtime, ASP.NET Core, HttpClient and dozens more) most major MS packages like EF Core, most major NuGet packages, eg EF Core. Other libraries either use ActivitySource already or one of the older tracing APIs (which means). You can collect all those traces and send them to an OTEL-compatible monitoring service like Jaeger which will show the sequence of calls as a tree, across services/microservices, queues etc

Comment: The *older* APIs like EventSource, Trace and DiagnosticSource are described in [Logging and Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing). The new ones in [Distributed Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing). Actually using them is easy as the [Instrumentation walkthrough shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs) shows. Visualizing the trace is infinitely better than anything DebugView could offer